# time.time () in python vs MicroPython

Tags: python, micropython

I am trying to run a python code on a pyboard using micro python. However the time.time() in Python returns the a floating point time in seconds. Ex: 12345678.12345678 While in micro python it only returns the time in seconds.
Ex: 12345678 is there a method in micro python that will give me the same accuracy as in python? It works in python but not in micro python. The loop stops after the first iteration in micro python without the condition being met.

while True:

```
# GAUGE DATA
if start_reading:
    t0 = time.time()
    while time.time() - t0 <1:
        data = ser_gauge.readline()
        print(data)
        if len(data) > 0:
            command = data
```

Comment: https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/utime.html#utime.ticks_us

Answer (score 0):

Embedded software usually doesn't have floating point precision to show the subsecond precision

[time.time() docs micropython](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/utime.html#utime.time)